# Video downloaded from OpenTok server has no sound

Tags: audio, video, video-streaming, audio-streaming, video-processing

I've successfully implemented the OpenTok. In group discussion (Three people, including moderator) video and **audio** transmission works well, but problem starts when moderator record stream. Video clip downloaded from OpenTok server has no sound.

Does anyone have any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ankur (OpenTok Forum):

> The audio stream in the downloaded videos is in the SPEEX codec. Many
>   desktop audio players don't recognize the codec. You may need to use
>   ffmpeg to transcode the audio before it is playable in programs like
>   VLC.